# Android How to use multiple pointers for dual joysticks

Tags: joystick

The app contains 2 virtual joysticks and I'm having trouble figuring out how to move them independently at the same time without the pointers getting mixed up.

Would someone be kind enough to give me some general advice?

I'd post what I have except it's so messy at this point I don't even know how it works. I'm just going to scrap it and start over.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the open source widgets of mobile-anarchy: https://code.google.com/p/mobile-anarchy-widgets/wiki/JoystickView

It provides code and samples for both single and dual virtual joysticks. Probably you can get some help by looking at their code, or maybe use those joysticks in your own application.